# how to find closest next img tag with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-selectors

I have a couple of these html blocks in a foreach loop:

```
<label class="">Replace video:</label>              
<input type="file" name="replaced_main_video" class="input-video-preview" />                                            
            
<!-- replaced main video -->            
<video class="video" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4">
</video>
<canvas></canvas>               
<label class="">Preview replaced video:</label><br />
<img class="video-preview" width="100" src="#" />
```

For showing a preview from the chosen video that is uploaded, is use this js code:

```
$(function() {
    var video = $('.video');
    var thumbnail = $('canvas');
    var input_video_preview = $('.input-video-preview');
    var ctx = thumbnail.get(0).getContext("2d");
    var duration = 0;
    var img = $('.video-preview');

    input_video_preview.on('change', function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        // Set video source
        video.find('source').attr('src', URL.createObjectURL(file));
        // Load the video
        video.get(0).load();
        // Load metadata of the video to get video duration and dimensions
        video.on('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
            duration = video.get(0).duration;
            // Set canvas dimensions same as video dimensions
            thumbnail[0].width = video[0].videoWidth;
            thumbnail[0].height = video[0].videoHeight;
            // Set video current time to get some random image
            video[0].currentTime = Math.ceil(duration / 2);
            // Draw the base-64 encoded image data when the time updates
            video.one("timeupdate", function() {
                ctx.drawImage(video[0], 0, 0, video[0].videoWidth, video[0].videoHeight);
                
                //$('.video-preview').attr("src", thumbnail[0].toDataURL());// THIS WORKS, but all imgs get src
                $('.input-video-preview').next('.video-preview').attr("src", thumbnail[0].toDataURL()); // bind to the next img with class 'video-preview'
            });
        });
    });
});
```

This works fine, but because the html blocks are repeated by a foreach, every `img` gets the source. and i want only the next `img` tag after the `input type="file"`

I tried to achieve this with this line below in the function:

```
$('.input-video-preview').next('.video-preview').attr("src", thumbnail[0].toDataURL()); // get input with class 'input-video-preview', take the next img with class '.video-preview' and bind it to the `src` attribute
```

But unfortunatley, this does not work....
How can i achieve this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/son4uqfa/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference the specific `input`, usually we use `$(this)` inside the function:

```
$(this).next('.video-preview')
```

instead of

```
$('.input-video-preview').next('.video-preview')
```

**Edit**

As you have many nested calls to `on()`, the command `$(this)` may change context and not target the `<input>` component. So you may need to do something like this:

```
input_video_preview.on('change', function(e) {
  var selectedInput = $(this);

   //...


  //...


  selectedInput.nextAll('.video-preview').eq( 0 ).attr("src", thumbnail[0].toDataURL());

});
```

**Edit 2**

Besides the topic of your question, there are other aspects of your code that may prevent it from working.

You should not before hand define the `video`, `thumbnail` and `img` vars. This vars depend on the input that was choosen.

So you should define than inside the `on()` using the `nextAll()` as well, like that:

```
$(function() {
  var input_video_preview = $('.input-video-preview');
  var duration = 0;

  input_video_preview.on('change', function(e) {
      var selectedInput = $(this);
    
      var video = selectedInput.nextAll('.video');
      var thumbnail = selectedInput.nextAll('canvas');
      var ctx = thumbnail.get(0).getContext("2d");
      var img = selectedInput.nextAll('.video-preview');
      var file = e.target.files[0];

    //...


  });
})
```

Comment: i tried this but i do not get a preview at all anymore...

Comment: I made a fiddle with this but still no preview: https://jsfiddle.net/son4uqfa/

Comment: you are defining `video`, `img` and `thumbnail` in the wrong place, see my edit 2 above

Comment: I am sorry, i updated my fiddle exactly with your edited code but cant get it work: https://jsfiddle.net/son4uqfa/3/

Comment: It is working now, one should use nextAll() instead of next() as next() just works for the very next sibling. I am updating my answer to reflect that.

Comment: I got it working with `.eq( 0 )` :https://jsfiddle.net/uqrfoLan/1/

Comment: `selectedInput.nextAll('.video-preview').eq( 0 ).attr("src", thumbnail[0].toDataURL());` did the trick! Thnx for this solution